# Is it possible to convert Ethernet to fiber optic to connect gpon modem

Tags: networking

I want to connect a GPON modem I brought to another GPON modem. I want to have 2 modems in 2 separate rooms only one modem can be connected to the fiber optic cable provided by my ISP.

Is there a way I can connect the other modem to one of the Ethernet port of the ISP modem and convert to fiber optic to connect to the other modem. Sorry but I don't know too much about networking I have a little understanding of it.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to connect two modems together?  What are you trying to achieve by doing that? Seems you would better of connecting a GIgabit Switch/Router to the GPON modem and calling it a day.  Fiber Optic cables are difficult to make, expensive to purchase, and you won't have any of the benefits if you have a media converter in the mix (which are also very expensive).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. But it's almost certainly not worth doing. To talk to a GPON device, you need a transmitter that's capable of talking to a GPON device. That's called an "OLT" and they tend to be expensive, $1,000 and up. This is because OLTs are typically used in configurations where they connect to dozens of devices, not just one, so typically have multiple ports often with at least one at speeds of 10Gb/s.

You don't really explain why you would want do to this, and honestly I can't think of any reason. If you just want another Gigabit Ethernet connection that shares your Internet access, connect an Ethernet cable to your router. If you want to do it over fiber, use Ethernet over fiber. It's cheap and simple.

Comment: I want to do it because I already brought the gpon modem to replace the one provided by my isp but they would not set it up due to there policy and the modem I brought has 5ghz wifi and the range is better. Seems like I have wanted my money. I should of asked my isp first.

Comment: @Ryan Oh, then you asked the wrong question entirely. You don't need or want to convert the Ethernet to fiber optic. You want to connect the GPON to your existing LAN. The fiber optic connection is for a WAN. In that case, you want to use its Ethernet port, not its fiber optic port because you want to connect it to your LAN and the Ethernet port is its LAN port.

Comment: Oh really would that work ? So I can just connect the Ethernet cable to one of the lan ports on the working modem and the other end to a lan port on the modem I brought and it would work ? Also there is 4 lan ports, 3 normal lan and one for iptv.

Comment: @Ryan Yes, that will work, assuming you can properly configure the device. For example, you need to be able to turn off its DHCP server.